# MySQL database backup using C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to take back up of a mysql database.
the code  i am created is

```
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
string cmd = string.Format(@"-u{0} -p{1} -E -R -h{2} {3}", UserName, PWD, hostname, dbname);
proc.FileName = "Path to mysqldump.exe";
proc.RedirectStandardInput = false;
proc.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.Arguments = cmd;
proc.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = Process.Start(proc);
string res;
res = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
file.WriteLine(res);
p.WaitForExit();
file.Close();
```

The problem is it working correctly when the database size is small but i am getting `Out Of Memory Exception` when i am trying to take back up of large database (Approximately 800 MB ).

Comment: Error message explains many things.How much space do you have in C drive determine the space for backup operations as the temp memory is used while taking backups or any curd memory management.

Comment: @Pratik About 64 GB free space is there..

Comment: Method to read the database file can u post sample as this could be the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reading the standard output in C# why don't you write it directly to file through the command line?

I typically take my mysqldumps using the following command. It works in both Windows and Linux.

```
mysqldump -u{user} -p{password} --routines --triggers --result-file={dest_filename} {dbname}
```

-OR-

```
mysqldump -u{user} -p{password} --routines --triggers {dbname} > {dest_filename}
```

The `Out of memory` exception you encountered would probably have been caused when trying to read the entire output of mysqldump to memory in C# on the following line (typically happens when a string exceeds beyond a certain size).

```
res = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Thank you Tanzeel let me try.

Comment: I think ">" is for dos command it giving me error "couldn't find table >"

Comment: @Vijesh Yes that's right as I stated in the answer `through the command line`. You can use the first suggestion using `--result-file` parameter or you can run it via `cmd /c "{command to run}"` as well.

Comment: @Rakesh can u share the code... i am also looking for similar solution

Answer (score 0):

Looks like very big string ate the memory.

Try to use OutputDataReceived event to write data in output file.

Here are two links with examples -

1. [Process.OutputDataReceived Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx)
2. [Process.BeginOutputReadLine Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx)